# How to keypaginate UUID in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, uuid

I want to paginate an User table with 10k+ registers, in the best way possible. I could use offset and limit, but it is clearly not good as I can see in many articles. Stumbled across keyset and cursor pagination, in which I though that keyset may be a better fit, since its easier to implement in APIs (im using golang). The problem is how the keyset works, from what I could see, the id (primary key) is indexed, then used to query across the database:

```
select * from users where id > ? order by id limit ?
```

However, it seems like this is only viable in integer auto-incremental IDs, and that's not my case, im using UUIDs (v4).
How can I achieve this keyset pagination?

Comment: There is nothing there that is restricted to integers.  You can use UUID just fine.  It does mean you will have to page through in UUID order, which is perhaps no the most natural thing to order by.  But you have a natural order you want to you, you need to mention it.

Comment: Suppose I would order by name. I need to set the index, get the first load of data (limit 500), and then get the last ID and use it in a where id > ID?
select * from user where id > ? (I guess this goes empty) limit 500;
select * from user where id > uuidfromlastrow limit 500;

Comment: If you want to order name, then you would just use the uuid as a tie breaker, not the primary.  `WHERE (name, id)>(?,?) order by name, id limit 500`

Comment: I just want to order it to paginate, the real ordering would be done in the client side with the request pieces (good example https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Example--Synchronizing-with-server). I saw some examples with date (created_at/updated_at) with your piece of code, how does the uuid would interact in that query? wouldn't the uuid be useless if i'm filtering by date?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will work just the same with UUIDs. Assuming that `id` is the UUID primary key column, you can write

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE (order_col1, order_col2, id) > (<previous values>)
ORDER BY order_col1, order_col2, id
LIMIT <page size>;
```

This query can be supported by an index on `(order_col1, order_col2)`.

Comment: I tested it and its true, UUIDs do not matter (that much), however, I have another problem, how could I sort by like, 4 columns + (one at time) and filter all the columns with only one filter (input text, by example)?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You should open a new question and supply more details.

Comment: I didn't know you could compare multiple values in a single Postgresql expression! I'd like to learn more about this in their docs. What's this kind of comparison called?

`WHERE (order_col1, order_col2, id) > (<previous values>)`

Comment: @EugeneKim I don't think that there is a special name, it is the comparison of *row expressions* or *composite types*. I don't know if the documentation covers that specifically, but the comparison is *lexicographical*: first, the first elements are compared. If that is not enough to determine the outcome, the second elements are compared, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LaurenzAlbe. It would've been nice to have something mentioned in the official documentation but in the world of stack overflow and helpful folks like yourself maybe it doesn't matter so much. Cheers!

Comment: @EugeneKim https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html

Row constructor comparison

Comment: I don't see how paginating using a uuid v4 could work @LaurenzAlbe since afaik UUID v4 are completely random. For example, a newly inserted record could very well end up as the first record if `order by uuid` is used, making pagination impossible.

Comment: @Perennialista That makes no difference, since `id` is the last `ORDER BY` column. It only acts as a tie-breaker.

Comment: I see, still one of the columns needs to be monotonically orderable, like `createdAt`. A column like `name` would not work for pagination, even when paired with uuid as a tie breaker. Say my users table looks like `[(Jack, 'uuid-abcd')]`, and I want to paginate returning one record at a time, adding a new record `('Abe', 'uuid-efgh')` would push `Jack` to the second page making pagination unreliable. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76057367/postgresql-keyset-pagination-query-not-working-with-uuid-v4-searchafter) also talks about using `uuid` as a tie-breaker but with `created_at`.

Comment: @Perennialista I wouldn't call that unreliable. It reflects a changing reality. If you need a stable snapshot of the data, you have to materialize the result set or use a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Thanks @LaurenzAlbe!